# When a popover row is selected, how is - (void)setDetailItem:(id)newDetailItem called?

Tags: iphone, uipopovercontroller, popover

I've created a TabBar application and in one of the views I'm using a popover.  The view is registered for UIPopoverControllerDelegate but that doesn't do it.  The popover is a completely different view controller and xib.  When the user selects a row in the popover, control goes to the popovercontroller.m method
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.  This tutorial helped a lot. [UIPopoverController Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1056/ipad-for-iphone-developers-101-uipopovercontroller-tutorial)

See the following files - ColorPickerController & RightViewController

Comment: The tutorial is great. Really helped me to understand how to use delegates with popovers.

Answer (score 1):

We had a similar question and found that DetailItem is a property.  Check out our blog for more information.
http://totalintmobile.tumblr.com/post/2623272838/what-calls-setdetailitem-in-uisplitview-template